# Error related to textures in unity 3d android in a built game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, blender

So for my game i made 2 models 1 of car and other a character both with blender they both seem good when played in play mode but when built the textures of my character just turn black while car remain same pls help me out. I tried another android device with higher API LEVEL but no luck

image of car has beautiful textures but character turned black

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but sometimes, your Shaders referenced in Materials aren't included in the Build. To ensure they are, go to Project Settings -> Graphics -> Always Included Shaders, and add any you might suspect missing to the list there.